# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1054

Tags: php, codeigniter

The Error Message is `Champ 'j.user_id=$user_id inconnu dans` where clause

```
SELECT `j`.`job_id`, `j`.`user_id`, `b`.`business_name`, `b`.`contract_person`, `b`.`mobile_number`, `b`.`email`, `b`.`id` 
FROM (`ci_jobs_apply` as j, `ci_business` as b) 
WHERE `j`.`user_id=$user_id` and j.job_id=b.id`
```

I want to join these two tables `Jobs_apply` and `Business` for checking the jobs applied on a job posting portal.

`jobs_apply` table contains fields like, `job_id` and `user_id`. And `Business` table contains like `user_id`, `business_name`, `contract_person`, `mobile_no`, `email` and so on.

I tried changing the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever `JOIN` syntax you've used there, I'm not familiar with it. You also had the following, which is incorrect:

```
`j`.`user_id=$user_id`
```

If you're going to use the backticks, it would be this:

```
`j`.`user_id` = $user_id
```

Assuming `$user_id` is an integer (I also put single quotes around this type in the `WHERE` clause in case `$user_id` is empty for some reason; this helps prevent unnecessary syntax errors). However, backticks are rarely necessary (when column names are also reserved words or there is a space, for instance).

Putting it together, with my own syntax style:

```
SELECT
   j.job_id
 , j.user_id
 , b.business_name
 , b.contract_person
 , b.mobile_number
 , b.email
 , b.id 
FROM ci_jobs_apply AS j
INNER JOIN ci_business AS b ON j.job_id = b.id
WHERE j.user_id = '$user_id'
```